# Is there a way to set a default parameter in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I recently tested out the `call` and `transfer` methods for a vulnerability of a contract and I realized I was being redundant in when I called the transferEth, I kept copypasting the address when I had it saved to a variable, `defaultAddress`. But I manually sent in the address through the function parameter in `transferEth` because I flipped between the default contract address and EOAs to make sure the transferring ETH method I used at the time worked (I am using `call` in the below example). So it had me thinking, can I set a default function parameter in solidity? How do I do so?

````
contract TestTransfer{

    address payable defaultAddress;

    event TransferSuccess(bool success, address sender, address recepient, uint value);

    constructor(address payable _defaultAddress){
        defaultAddress = _defaulAddress;
    }

    function transferEth(address _receipient) payable external {
        (bool success, /*bytes memory data*/) = _receipient.call{value: msg.value}("");
        emit TransferSuccess(success, msg.sender, _receipient, msg.value);
    }

}```
````

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolved your issue, or comment if you need any further help...

Answer (score 3):

Solidity doesn't support optional function parameters, at least for now (maybe in the future, at least there has been some discussions about it).

But, you can use function overloading to simulate it for now, with something like this:

```
contract TestTransfer{

    address payable defaultAddress;

    event TransferSuccess(bool success, address sender, address recepient, uint value);

    constructor(address payable _defaultAddress){
        defaultAddress = _defaulAddress;
    }

    function transferEth() payable external {
        transferEth(defaultAddress);
    }

    function transferEth(address _receipient) payable external {
        (bool success, /*bytes memory data*/) = _receipient.call{value: msg.value}("");
        emit TransferSuccess(success, msg.sender, _receipient, msg.value);
    }
}
```